# PHP: Determine whether class is extension of another class

Tags: php, oop, reflection

How do you test to see if a class extends another class by name?

```
class A { ... }
class B extends A { ... }
class C { ... }

$class_name = 'B';
if (class_extends_another($class_name, 'A')) {
   // Yep
}

$class_name = 'C';
if (class_extends_another($class_name, 'A')) {
   // Nope
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
get_parent_class()
```

is what you're looking for. Which will return the name of the parent class.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: Thanks for the link, it in-turn links to `is_subclass_of`. It looks like that should do the trick: `is_subclass_of($class_name, 'A')`

Answer (score 1):

I've have thought that the [class_parents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php) function would be the simplest solution, although it should be noted that this is only available in PHP 5.1 and above.

For example, if you wanted to see if 'B' extended 'A', you could use:

```
if(in_array('A', class_parents('B'))) {
    // B extends A.
}
```

Incidentally, it should be noted that as per the docs you can provide either an object (class instance) or a string (class name) to the `class_parents` function, which may prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you're looking for you might also want the `instanceof` operator.

`$a instanceof A` will be true if `$a` is an instance of class `A`, or any class which extends `A` (including if it is an instance of `C` which extends `B` which extends `A`) or which `implements A` (if you are using interfaces). See http://php.net/instanceof

Comment: In my scenario both operands are class names as opposed to instances. Thanks anyhow.